# Error: found : AnyVal required: Int, how to do auto type casting in Scala

Tags: scala

I am getting following error message:

```
[error]  found   : AnyVal
[error]  required: Int
```

But `Int` extends `AnyVal [1]` so I believe as in `Java`, `Integer` can be casted from `Object` why it's not working in `Scala`, what I am missing:

```
[1] final abstract class Int private extends AnyVal
```

I also tried with a simple example:

```
val a: AnyVal = 5

def aTob(a: Int): Int = a * 5

aTob(a)
```

> Error:(5, 73) type mismatch;
>
> found : AnyVal
>
> required: Int

But following works:

```
val a: Any = 5

def aTob(a: Int): Int = a * 5

aTob(a.asInstanceOf[Int])
```

I don't want to explicitly cast it, but it should be implicit casting.

> [Edit:] I also tried with `Any`

-

> Update:

```
def getValue(dType: String): Any = {

    dType.toLowerCase() match {

        case "double[3]" =>
            10d
        case "float" =>
            1f

}

val d = getValue("double[3]")
val f = getValue("float")

SomeClass(d, f)


case class SomeClass(val d : Double, val f: Float)
```

Comment: can you give a little more info about your use case? I'm interested to know why not have methods `getDouble` or `getFloat` if you know what type you're expecting?

Comment: @JoelBerkeley I have a parser, where I could have multiple types of data which I would know at runtime.

Comment: and the parser is generated at runtime, so its ugly to hardcode the method call for different types of user-defined datatypes @JoelBerkeley

Comment: You want "auto type-casting" but the given solution of using implicits (which you also mention in your question) is not valid? Please give an explicit example of why this would be the case.

Comment: Also to address your `AnyVal` to `Int`, it's a heirarchy. Every `Int` is an `AnyVal`, whereas not all `AnyVal`'s are `Int`. Many datatypes extend `AnyVal`. `Unit`, for example, is a non-numeric type, so using it as an `Int` doesn't make any sense, thus the explicit casting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use implicit conversion, but it is prone to error because you if you pass e.g. `Float` like `val a: AnyVal = 5.0F` you will get `ClassCastException`:

```
implicit def anyValToInt(anyVal: AnyVal): Int = anyVal.asInstanceOf[Int]

val a: AnyVal = 5

def aTob(a: Int): Int = a * 5

aTob(a)
```

Comment: I have multiple return types, but where ever I will access these values, I am sure about the type of the variable. So `implicit def` is not an option

Comment: Could you share a piece of your code when you get compile error if it is possible?

Comment: I have no idea besides defining implicit conversion for each type you know like `implicit def anyValToInt(...): Int`, `implicit def anyValToDouble(...): Double`, ... etc